# Syntax Error while trying to display user inputed salaries within a range of the mean

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the module that will input a two-dimensional array containing employee names and their corresponding salaries

```
salary = []
names = []

def floatInput():
    done = False
    while not done:
        nameIn = input("Please enter the employee name or * to finish: ")
        salaryIn = input("Please enter the salary in thousands for " + nameIn + ": ")
        try:
            salaryIn = float(salaryIn)
        except:
            print("I was expecting a positive floating point number!")
        if nameIn == "*":
           done = True
        else:
            salary.append(salaryIn)
            names.append(nameIn)
        return salaryIn
        return nameIn

floatInput()
```

here I use a for loop to print and iterate through the list of names and salaries.

```
for i in range(len(names)):
    print(names[i] + ", " + str(salary[i]))
```

Here I find the mean of the salaries.

```
def salaryMean():
    mean = sum(salary) / float(len(salary))
    print("The mean of the salaries is: " + str(mean))
    return mean

salaryMean()
```

here I convert the salary to thousands.

```
for i in range(len(names)):
    salary = salary[i] * 1000
```

Here I display all employees who earn within a range of $5,000 from the mean
This where I am getting a syntax error.  Please help.

```
def displayNames():
    done = False
    x = 0
    while not done:
        if salary[x] >= (mean - 5000) and salary[x] <= (mean + 5000) 
        print(salary[x])
        x += 1
        if x > len(salary)
        done = True

displayNames()
```

Comment: You're missing colons (as well as indentation on the line after) at the end of the if blocks

Comment: Yes, and indent the following lines that you want to conditionally execute inside the if block

Comment: Thank you for the help people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def displayNames():
    done = False
    x = 0
    while not done:
        if done:
            break
        if salary[x] >= (mean - 5000) and salary[x] <= (mean + 5000):
            print(salary[x])
        x += 1
        if x > len(salary):
            done = True

displayNames()
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed this problem.